# How do I compare a std::function's target with a member function's address?

Tags: c++, bind

I am trying to figure out how to compare a function object's target (which is a member function) with the actual member function.
Of course, they should match.

But I don't get them to match, and I am lost with the syntax for declaring a member function as the type for the function object.

Here is some code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;


class Object {
public:
    void method () {}
};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Object* obj = new Object();
    function<?????> wrapper = bind(&Object::method, obj);
    if (wrapper.target<?????>() == &Object::method) {
        cout << "match" << "\n";
    } else {
        cout << "no match" << "\n";
    }   
    delete(obj);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to put different things instead of the ?????, but without any success.

So, what do I write instead of the questions marks, or are there other problems with this code?

Comment: I'm suspect that this is not possible.

Comment: Well, `wrapper` should probably be of type `function<void()>` (though it can take any number of arguments if you want it to, and they'll all be discarded).

Comment: I tried `function<void ()>`, but it starts complaining about the `if`-statement:
`main.cpp:26:44: error: invalid operands of types 'void (*)()' and 'void (Object::*)()' to binary 'operator=='`

Comment: Unrelated to the main problem, why are you using `new` and `delete` here?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Seems like the OP is following [this modern principle](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/308245).

Comment: @ Kerrek SB: Not at all :).
@ Jonathan Wakely: I am new to C++ and I have not learned the proper way of modern C++ yet.

Comment: [Avoid `new` and `delete` outside of resource management functions](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-new)

Comment: Did you want to check whether the function object is pointing to the correct function on the correct object, or merely the correct function?

Comment: @ Jonathan Wakely: Thanks! that seems like a great document! It's in my bookmarks.

Comment: @ Richard Hodges: My aim was to store a bunch of `function` objects holding pointers to different member functions in a `vector`. That works, but when I have to remove one of them, I have to check which one it is (given a pointer to the member function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> function<?????> wrapper = bind(&Object::method, obj);
> ```

The bind expression returns a callable object that requires no arguments and returns `void`, so the logical call signature is `void()` and so you want `std::function<void()>`.

> ```
> if (wrapper.target<?????>() == &Object::method) {
> ```

This won't work, because the `function` doesn't hold the pointer-to-member-function, it holds the result of the `bind` expression, which wraps the pointer-to-member-function.

The type returned by the bind expression (and therefore the type of the `function`'s target) is some internal implementation detail such as `_Binder<void, _Mem_fn<Object, void()>, Object*>`, which you can't refer to directly.

You could do:

```
auto b = bind(&Object::method, obj);
function<void()> wrapper = b;
if (wrapper.target<decltype(b)>() != nullptr) {
```

But this doesn't tell you anything useful.

Comment: The bind expression really returns a callable object that takes any amount of arguments conceivable, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, true, so you could use `function<void(any, thing, whatsoever)>` but the sensible call signature is `void()`. I'll reword it slightly.

Comment: This kinda sucks then. It is a good explanation. I have to find another way then. Thanks! (Sorry if I am not supposed to say this here)